# How to investigate vague "js/chunk-venders... from Terser" undefined failure?

Tags: webpack, vue-cli, vue-cli-3, webpack-plugin, terser

My Vue-CLI project is failing to create a production build:

```
⠏  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                       21:21:03

 error  

js/chunk-vendors.fd39f4a0.js from Terser
undefined

 ERROR  Build failed with errors.
```

I can get it to build by disabling Terser. What is quite weird is that I have used [this project template](https://github.com/stevage/community-map) many times before, and am not doing anything particularly different in this project (a couple of slightly different modules, but exactly the same build process etc as usual).

In [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59773061/how-can-i-debug-this-webpack-error-error-in-bundle-js-from-terser) the output contained a line number which could be used for debugging, but mine doesn't. All I know is that *something* is undefined.

Google searches suggest that rolling back to specific Terser versions, but:

1. I have terser-webpack-plugin 1.2.1 and terser 3.14.1 which seem to be the recommended ones; and
2. These versions have been working for dozens of similar projects.

With a bit of trial and error I have now deduced that the problems lie with importing the module [mapbox-gl-draw-circle](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapbox-gl-draw-circle), but my question remains:

**How do you actually investigate (and fix, rather than simply workaround) a problem like this with Terser?**